# Twitter sign-in inPlay Framework

Tags: java, oauth, playframework, twitter-oauth, playframework-2.4

I am trying to create an application that interacts with users'twitter accounts. 
(Tweets based on triggers).
This is my first time interacting with OAuth, so please bare with my ignorance :).

I think I need two things :

- Have users authorize the app so that I can perform operations on their behalf. As far as I understand the authorization is a one time only operation.
- Allow users to sign in the application using Twitter.

I have followed the excellent [JAvaOAuth](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaOAuth) tutorial and I already am successfully posting tweets. 
The problem is that the tokens in the example are stored in a cookie, meaning that closing the browser deletes everything. Every time I access the application again I am redirected to the **Authorization** page.

To make things more permanent, I understand I have to save those tokens in the database. 
Now this is fine, but how do I handle **Sign in** ? Is it a completely different workflow? The [implementing sign-in](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) page of the Twitter docs is so close from what is performed in the JavaOAuth tutorial that I am a bit lost.

I guess I could implement sign-in myself, but since I only interact with Twitter I think using Twitter sign-in would be way neater.

Last but not least, I have looked at [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/) but sadly the project looks on a standstill and is still only 2.3 compliant.

Any direction on how to implement sign-in in a correct way would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, after reading more and more doc, I may be coming closer to the solution. This page seems to explain the difference : https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so [this documentation page](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged) helped me as expected.

To get this answer working fine, you will have to already have implemented the sample documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaOAuth).

Then, as mentioned in the documentation, simply replace this url :

> https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize

with this :

> https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authenticate

in your sample.

Annnnnd, this should work fine. Easier than expected :).

Answer (score 1):

> I have looked at SecureSocial but sadly the project looks on a standstill and is still only 2.3 compliant.

There is one project that use securesocial concept and can handle twitter sign-in: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate

For installing it I used dependency:

```
"com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

and resolver:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
```

because `"com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.7.0"` did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'd rather work without introducing dependencies whenever possible though and understand what happens under the hood. Cheers!